# MonoGame Windows 8 - WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, monogame

If you place the following code in the game loop (Update or Draw) of a MonoGame app (can just be the default project template):

```
new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(150, 150);
```

It throws a cross-thread error...

```
The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
```

So then I tried this:

```
var dispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
{
     new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(150, 150);
});
```

Same error.

Looking under the covers, it doesn't look like MonoGame runs the game loop on a background thread or anything.  It uses a synchronous loop.

Any ideas of a way to use `WriteableBitmap` in MonoGame?  (I need to use it to render out some live tiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Game class then your creating an application that by default does not support XAML.

Currently the best way to support XAML in a MonoGame app is to use the Siverlight-style XNA game as outlined in this thread...

http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/359544

Comment: Got it working by making a Windows 8 specific subclass of my main `Game` object.  Then used `GameTimer` inside it to call `Update` and `Draw` respectively.  The Xaml side of the application just has to new up my `Game` class, and everything starts up.